# ASP.NET Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style') at OpenListBox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

We have a client website where dropdowns stop working.

Google Console shows the following:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
> at OpenListBox (Location_Edit.aspx?lid=11502:47)
> at HTMLSpanElement.onclick (Location_Edit.aspx?lid=11502:623)

Code for this section is as follows:
** is line 623 where error is noted.

```
<div>
    <table id="canvas_multiSelectDropDown1_Table2" 
           style="TABLE-LAYOUT: fixed; HEIGHT: 24px" 
           borderColorDark="#cccccc" borderColorLight="#7eb3e3" 
           cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" 
           border="1">
        <tr id="canvas_multiSelectDropDown1_rowDD" ** style="HEIGHT: 15px">
            <TD nowrap="nowrap">
                    <span id="canvas_multiSelectDropDown1_DDLabel" onclick="OpenListBox(&#39;ctl00_canvas_multiSelectDropDown1_&#39;);" style="display:inline-block;border-color:Transparent;border-style:None;font-family:Arial;font-size:Smaller;height:15px;width:250px;CURSOR: default">VSP  - Xerox Phaser 6600 (Black)</span></TD>**
            <TD id="canvas_multiSelectDropDown1_colDDImage" style="PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #7eb3e3" width="20" background="images/DDImage.bmp" onclick="OpenListBox(&#39;ctl00_canvas_multiSelectDropDown1_&#39;);"></TD>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

---

Looking further I ....is it possible error is in the set of code: OpenListBox

---

```
    function OpenListBox(ctlId) {
        var lstBox = document.getElementById(ctlId + "DDList");
        if (lstBox.style.visibility == "visible")
        { CloseListBox(ctlId); }
        else {
            lstBox.style.visibility = "visible";
            lstBox.style.height = "120px";
        }
    }
```

_________________-

Issue solved: This was a recently migrated website- after migrating I noticed: Current verison iss Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3905.0

The solution was to roll back to Microsoft .NET Framework version 2.0

Comment: try removing the styling for the span and see if it works, also may want to look at the apostrophe encoding &#39; in the onclick OpenListBox call,

Comment: I am having trouble finding the code in the .aspx file. Is it referring to another location.

Comment: Your Javascript function calls are passing in a prefix of `ctl00_canvas_multiSelectDropDown1_`; but the elements in your markup seem to have a prefix of `canvas_multiSelectDropDown1_`, without the `ctl00_` at the start. You need to find the code that's generating these attributes.

Comment: Hey Richard.....looking at the code placed by a previous developer on the project it appears the  ctl00 id was coded into the master file.  Any idea why they would have done this??  _________________          <script language="javascript">
        function SelectedIndexChanged(ctlId) {
            var control = document.getElementById(ctlId + 'DDList');
            var strSelText = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < control.length; i++) {
                if (control.options[i].selected) {
                    strSelText += control.options[i].text + ',';
                }

Comment: Issue solved: This was a recently migrated website- after migrating I noticed: Current verison iss Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3905.0

The solution was to roll back to Microsoft .NET Framework version 2.0